# Building a compound probability distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I want to build a probability distribution for a "shock" variable. I want to show that there are p% chances of no shock, and (100-p)% chances of shock- in which case, shock is distributed according to some continuous pdf f(x). I have absolutely no ides how to do it. Please help. Thanks for any suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As non-statician I dislike percentages and my $p$ stand for your p%.

Maybe something like: $$X:=US$$ where $U$ and $S$ are independent random variables.

This with $P(U=1)=p$ and $P(U=0)=1-p$ and with $S$ having PDF $f$.

$U$ somehow states whether there is a shock or not.

$S$ somehow "measures" a shock (and is probably meant to be positive).

$X$ is (if $p>0$) not continuous and for $x\geq0$ we have $$P(X\leq x)=(1-p)+pP(S\leq x)$$

Comment: Thanks for your help drhab.
So, does it mean that if there is a probability of 0.75 (p) of shock, and 0.25 (1-p) for no shock, when shock is uniformly distributed over [0,1], then: overall probability of getting a shock of measure 0.33 will be:
P(X<0.33)=0.25+0.75*0.33=0.4975?

Comment: Not the probability of getting a shock of measure $0.33$, but the probability of getting a shock *less than* $0.33$ will equalize that.

Comment: Thank you so much drhab. You have been a great help.

Comment: You are very welcome.